# Counting factors with other columns and placing the result in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with three columns, species (factor) year (numeric) and disease status (factor). Disease status has two levels - "Negative" and "Positive". I want to count for each species in each year how many negative and positive results there are and place the result into a data frame. I only want one row for each species in each year for each disease status.

```
    Species Year Disease_status
1 Hedgehog 1870       Positive
2 Hedgehog 1870       Positive
3   Badger 1990       Negative
4 Blue Tit 1991       Negative

LOP <- as.data.frame(with(Book1, tapply(Species, 
list(Disease_status, Year), FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))))
```

The code above is as far as I've gotten, but only produces a data frame with the number of species with a negative or positive result in a year, but not the number of individuals within a species with a positive or negative result in a year.

Comment: That gives multiple rows for species in each year for each disease status

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure whether this is what you need, but I thought of the following solution, which is based on the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) package:

```
df <- tibble(
  "Species" = as.factor(c("Hedgehog", "Hedgehog", "Badger", "Blue Tit")),
  "Years" = as.numeric(c(1870, 1870, 1990, 1991)),
  "Disease_status" = as.factor(c("positive", "positive", "negative", "negative"))
)

summary <- df %>%
  group_by(Species, Years) %>%
  count(Disease_status)
```

This yields:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Species, Years [3]
   Species Years Disease_status     n
    <fctr> <dbl>         <fctr> <int>
1   Badger  1990       negative     1
2 Blue Tit  1991       negative     1
3 Hedgehog  1870       positive     2
```

In case you want to have %>% spread(Disease_status, n, fill = 0) at the end of the pipeline (as suggested by Ben Bolker), the output is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Species, Years [3]
   Species Years negative positive
*   <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1   Badger  1990        1        0
2 Blue Tit  1991        1        0
3 Hedgehog  1870        0        2
```

Comment: I think the author wants you to `%>% spread(Disease_status,n)` at the end of that pipeline (and what's with the `print()` ?)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the tidyverse but with this solution must I enter all the data manually? How could I apply this to a larger data set without entering all the data manually?

Comment: @Ben Bolker, I see, I am going to edit my answer to include this last line as well. The print() was just to display the tibble after running the code; it's probably better to remove it.

Comment: @KLP no you don't, but I entered the data manually so you can better understand what I did. You can convert a data.frame into a tibble by using the as.tibble() command.

Comment: one more suggestion, use `fill=0` in your `spread()` so the 'missing' values get filled with 0 rather than NA

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this task in R. Using base R functions, it can be accomplished as follows.

```
rawData <- "Species Year Disease_status
Hedgehog 1870       Positive
Hedgehog 1870       Positive
Hedgehog 1870       Negative
Hedgehog 1870       Negative
Hedgehog 1870       Negative
Hedgehog 1870       Negative
Hedgehog 1871       Negative
Hedgehog 1871       Negative
Badger 1870      Positive
Badger 1870      Positive
Badger 1870      Positive
Badger 1870      Positive
Badger 1870      Positive
Badger 1870      Negative
Badger 1870      Negative
Badger 1870      Negative
Blue_Tit 1991       Negative"

theData <- read.table(textConnection(rawData),header=TRUE,
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
theData$count <- 1
aggData <- aggregate(count ~ Disease_status + Year + Species,
                 data=theData,sum)
aggData
```

The output is as follows.

```
> aggData
  Disease_status Year  Species count
1       Negative 1870   Badger     3
2       Positive 1870   Badger     5
3       Negative 1991 Blue_Tit     1
4       Negative 1870 Hedgehog     4
5       Positive 1870 Hedgehog     2
6       Negative 1871 Hedgehog     2
>
```

If the output requires two columns of Positive and Negative for Disease_status, this can be accomplished with the `reshape2` package as follows.

```
library(reshape2)
theData <- read.table(textConnection(rawData),header=TRUE,
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
theData$count <- 1
dcast(theData, Year + Species ~ Disease_status,
      value.var="count",sum)
```

And the output:

```
> dcast(theData, Year + Species ~ Disease_status,value.var="count",sum)
  Year  Species Negative Positive
1 1870   Badger        3        5
2 1870 Hedgehog        4        2
3 1871 Hedgehog        2        0
4 1991 Blue_Tit        1        0
>
```

Comment: The OP is being unclear, but I think they want a column for Negative and Positive within each year

Comment: There is really no need to present  the output as an image. :(

Comment: Updated for alternate solution with 2 one row per year / species, two columns of disease status. @RomanLuštrik - I'm new to SO, in other venues people appreciate the output screenshots. Is it against etiquette on SO to post them?

Comment: At least in the [r] tag, we generally have a strong preference for cut-and-pasted text rather than a screenshot (among other things, it's more accessible to visually impaired readers)

Comment: @BenBolker screenshots replaced with cut and pasted text.